# What's the best way to sort MAP<String, Object> by value in Dart programming?

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart

I'm new to dart programming, I came from a Javascript environment
everything is fresh to me and I really have no Idea how this sorting works
in dart.

Here's an example from my API

```
List example = [
 {"id": "1", "age": "20"},
 {"id": "2", "age": "21"},
 {"id": "3", "age": "22"},
]
```

Before I will assign "example" to other variables eg.

```
var example2 = example;
```

I want to sort it by "age", I found libs and other "LONG" solutions out there but feels like there's another way.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is sort function for list. Try reading the documentation a bit:

```
void main() {
List example = [
 {"id": "1", "age": "20"},
 {"id": "2", "age": "19"},
 {"id": "3", "age": "22"},
 {"id": "4", "age": "9"},
];
  print(example);
  
  example.sort((x,y) => x["age"].compareTo(y["age"]));
  print(example);
}
```

EDIT: Your definition should contain integers logically:

```
void main() {
List example = [
 {"id": 1, "age": 20},
 {"id": 2, "age": 19},
 {"id": 3, "age": 22},
 {"id": 4, "age": 9},
];
  print(example);
  
  example.sort((x,y) => x["age"].compareTo(y["age"]));
  print(example);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really confused about List in dart sorry for this silly question

Comment: I'll just add that you'll if you're trying to sort by age you probably want to parse out an int value like so `  example.sort((x, y) => int.parse(x["age"]).compareTo(int.parse(x["age"])));
` It still works without `int.parse` until you try with much larger numbers

Comment: @SuperKola, np. Note that with this style sorting is in alphabetical order. Your values are string (quoted).

Comment: @Loren.A, no I wouldn't do it. If the data is string then naturally an alpha sort is wanted. Here logically the map was wrong, made up of strings instead of integers. IOW it is an error at initial definition.

Comment: @Loren.A yes I just parsed it, Thanks! gonna read more in docs

Comment: @CetinBasoz you've just saved a lot of my time thanks for this! gonna read more in docs... strongly typed language is really confusing for me.

Comment: @Cetin I agree that it should be an int to begin with. All I'm saying is that if one is trying to return a list sorted by age in that example that would work with any value of age, then int.parse is more reliable. The age still remains a string.

Comment: I edited to show correct definition. It really doesn't make sense to start with strings for age and then parse. Also in case of strings extra check is needed if it can be casted to int.